# Java Timer next execution time

Tags: java, timer

Meet Janitor, a timer that runs everyday at 3am.

```
Timer janitorTimer = new Timer();
TimerTask janitorWorker = new Janitor(); // Extending TimerTask
long delay = TimeUtils.getMillisUntilTomorrowAt( 3L * 3600000L); // Does what it says
janitorTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate( janitorWorker, delay, 24L * 3600000L);
```

At certain point in time I would like to know **when is next janitorWorker execution**.

 Couldn't find anything relevant in Timer nor TimerTask. 
Feels that something either should already know.

Comment: Are you looking for `TimerTask.scheduledExecutionTime()` (see API docs)?

Comment: @Jesper: it looks like scheduledExectionTime() returns the scheduled execution time for the last time the task was executed, not the *next* time.

Comment: There is nothing out of the box. Thansk for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your implementation of  `TimerTask` you could expose the the `nextExecutionTime`, and then comapre that to the current time, see the `mainLoop` in `Timer`

Comment: Saving nextExecutionTime in TimerTask would not work since multiple timers may execute this task at different times.

Answer (score 0):

In the case when task hasn't executed yet, method  [scheduledExecutionTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#scheduledExecutionTime--) is undefined. However, in my application, where once-executing task is scheduled, this method in fact returns scheduled time both before and after executing.
**Note** This behaviour is device-specific and non-documented. So, this approach should be verified for each device and cannot be recommended in general.

Comment: As Sean Reilly's comment on the question mentions, the documentation states that `scheduledExecutionTime` gives the time the *last* run was *supposed* to run. It's not supposed to return the *next* execution time, which is what the question asked.

Comment: Yes, I've read documentation and, of course, scheduledExecutionTime is designed for time of the latest execution. However, in the case of once-executing task, I see that it returns the time of the only scheduled execution, even if this time in future.
PS I'm not sure that it is the same on all devices.
PPS Thanks for editing my post. I also tried to format hyperlink, but couldn't manage.

Comment: Ah, all right—I missed that nuance when I read your answer. The fact that you're mentioning undocumented behaviour should perhaps be noted in the answer, and in general one should probably not rely on this behaviour as it may break on different versions or distributions of Java.

Comment: Answer is updated (with **Note** inserted). Thanks for a valuable suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

In [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html), exists a method called `scheduledExecutionTime()`. What it does is:

> Returns the scheduled execution time of the most recent actual
>   execution of this task.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#scheduledExecutionTime%28%29

**UPDATE:**

Here is a new way.

Because it has a fixed rate, what you could do is call `scheduledExecutionTime()` add to it the **fixedRate** value and you then deduce the **nextExecutionTime**.

Comment: scheduledExecutionTime gives LAST, I am after NEXT execution time.

Comment: _Returns:
    the time at which the most recent execution of this task was scheduled to occur, in the format returned by Date.getTime(). The return value is undefined if the task has yet to commence its first execution._